# magento2 home page load very slow when user visit first time

Tags: magento2, lazyload

In my home page I have slider, some dynamic category images, some dynamic products and blogs. When user visit first time it's very slow.

Could anyone suggest me how I load part by part, not all at one time.
I want to say, using lazy load how I load one by one block.

Slider, category image, products and blog all are configure by magento widgets.

My home page url is: https://www.lapisbard.com/

Comment: The scrolling on the page also crashes for me.

Comment: did you enable product mode and cache?

Comment: I am using magento2 Varnish Cache for Full page caching. But, I am not able to get the meaning of "product mode"